# structのメンバを文字列で指定して参照したい

Tags: c++

C言語で実装済みのコード(変更不可)に対し、C++で汎用的な処理を書く方法を検討しています。

たとえばC側に下記のような構造体定義があった場合に、

```
typedef struct
{
    int     nvalue;
    float   fvalue;
} Test_t;
```

C++で下記のCreate_strucure/Get_memberを実現する方法はありますでしょうか。

```
auto sparam = Create_structure("Test_t");
auto* pvalue_1 = Get_member(&sparam, "nvalue");
*pvalue_1 = 1;
auto* pvalue_2 = Get_member(&sparam, "fvalue");
*pvalue_2 = 2.3;

//Create_strucure : 文字列で指定されたstruct型を返却
//Get_member：引数1で指定された変数のメンバ(引数1.引数2)を返却
```

目的は、膨大な数のstuructに対して汎用的に使用可能な処理を書くことです。
struct/member参照を文字列で行うことができれば楽だと思うのですが、そういったことは可能でしょうか。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: こんな記事が何かヒントになるかもしれません。[C++でもGetComponentがしたい！](https://tech.drecom.co.jp/ac2019-do_not_escape_cpp/), [ClangにReflection提案っぽいものを実装してみた話 - Speaker ...](https://speakerdeck.com/hori1991/clangnireflectionti-an-tupoimofalsewoshi-zhuang-sitemitahua), [Celtoys/clReflect](https://github.com/Celtoys/clReflect), [リフレクション (C++/CLI)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/cpp/dotnet/reflection-cpp-cli?view=msvc-160), [Slightly Less Costly but Much Usable C++ Reflection with Singular Inheritance Rule](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/5065528/Slightly-Less-Costly-but-Much-Usable-Cplusplus-Ref)

Comment: ちなみに、`Get_member(&sparam, "nvalue")`は `int*` を返し、 `Get_member(&sparam, "fvalue")` は `float*` を返すことになりますが、それだと呼び出し側はメンバ名に対応するデータ型を知っている必要があります。その点はどうお考えでしょうか？

Comment: @kunif さん：大変参考になるリンクを教えていただきありがとうございます！勉強させていただきます。

Comment: @sayuri さん：memberの名前を使った参照が可能なら、型も取ってこれそうだなぁ…と安直に考えておりました(だとすると、サンプルとして書いたコードでは足りないのですが…)。名前を使った参照自体が複雑そうだということは分かったので、型名取得も併せて検討したいです。ご指摘いただきありがとうございます。

Comment: しつこくてすみません。興味深い話題ではあるものの現状ほぼ不可能でして。型も併せてとのことですが、例えば`char*`なら`sprintf`するなど型がわかってもそれに合わせた処理が必要に思います。なぜ名前でアクセスしたいのかもう一段深い事情を説明いただけたらまた別のアプローチが見つかるかもと考えています。

Comment: @sayuri さん：いえ、とても勉強になっているのでありがたいです。事情を具体的に書きますと、Cコードに対してC++でテストコードを書きたいというのが目的です。色んな構造体に対してあらゆる値をセットするためのコードをいちいち書くのが大変→CSV等で構造体/member名を記述しておいて、テストコードは読み込んだCSVを元に構造体/memberを作成するだけにできればメンテが楽なのでは？という考えで質問しました。(ただ、仰るようにchar*や配列を同じ扱いにするのは厳しそうなので、それ以外だけでも…という感じでした)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

変更不可の実装済みのコードがコンパイル済みライブラリとして提供されていて、Test_tも不透明型として提供されている場合は、情報が失われているので不可能です。

ヘッダーファイルはあるけれど変更はできないという状況でしたら、事前に`clang -Xclang -ast-dump=json`でヘッダーを解析しASTをファイルにダンプしておいて、実行時にJSONから読みだして引き当てることは原理的には可能だと思います。

実際に Clang libtooling で同様のことをやっているツール＆ライブラリがありました。
https://github.com/mlomb/MetaCPP

コメントにある「C++でもGetComponentがしたい！」もVisualStudioでの似たような話のようです。

Comment: コメントいただきありがとうございます。

環境は、「ヘッダーファイルはあるけれど変更できない」方です。
なるほど、構造体の名前情報なんて人間しか要らないですもんね……ヘッダーファイルを解析するしかないんですね。

「C++でも～」は熟読中だったのですが、便利そうなライブラリをご紹介いただきありがとうございます。
実現したいことが可能かどうか、こちらも併せて確認させていただきます。

お時間いただきありがとうございました。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 3):

既に回答がある通り、C言語・C++言語どちらもコンパイルを行うとその時点でポインターやオフセットの形でコード生成され、型情報は削除されます。そのため、実行時にメンバー名でアクセスすることはできません。

2020/12/11にリリースされたBoost Version 1.75（現時点での最新版）から[PFRというヘッダーオンリーライブラリ](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/doc/html/boost_pfr.html)が追加されています。
このライブラリを使うと、メンバー名でアクセスすることはできませんが、[インデックスでアクセスする](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/doc/html/boost_pfr/tutorial.html#boost_pfr.tutorial.accessing_structure_member_by_in)ことは可能です。

```
auto sparam = Test_t{};
auto& value_1 = boost::pfr::get<0>(sparam);
value_1 = 1;
auto& value_2 = boost::pfr::get<1>(sparam);
value_2 = 2.3;
```

---

> Cコードに対してC++でテストコードを書きたいというのが目的です。色んな構造体に対してあらゆる値をセットするためのコードをいちいち書くのが大変→CSV等で構造体/member名を記述しておいて、テストコードは読み込んだCSVを元に構造体/memberを作成するだけにできればメンテが楽なのでは？

既にコメントの内容の表現を変えただけになりますが、テストデータを書くCSVにはCコードにどのようなメンバーがいるかを知っていなければなりませんし、C++コードはCSVにどのようなデータ型が出現するかを知っていなければなりません。CSVに未知のデータ型を書かれてもC++コードは処理できないわけです。
また、C++コードはCSVを処理しなければなりません。`int`なら`scanf("%d")`、`float`なら`scanf("%f")`等々、テストドライバー側の負担が大きく、テストが期待通りに動かないリスクも高まるので、あまりお勧めできないアプローチかなと思います。

なるべくシンプルにC++コードで、記述することを提案します。
例えば、C++20で導入された[指示付き初期化](https://cpprefjp.github.io/lang/cpp20/designated_initialization.html)という記述を使うと、メンバー名付きで初期化できます。

```
Test_t patterns[] = {
  { .nvalue = 1, .fvalue = 2.3, },
  { .nvalue = 2, .fvalue = 4.6, },
};
```

またC++17で導入された[`std::size`](https://cpprefjp.github.io/reference/iterator/size.html)を使うと配列の要素数も取得できます（`std::size(patterns)`は`2`となる）。上記データ配列を別ファイルに切り出し、C++コードに`#include ""`すれば、テストコードとテストデータを分離できます。

Comment: 回答いただきありがとうございます。最新のBoostであればこういったことも可能なのですね…。ビルド環境が最新のものではない(自分の意志でのupdateも難しい)ので現時点では使用できませんが、記憶に留めておきたいと思います。お時間いただきありがとうございました。

Comment: @Scott コメントを踏まえて追記しましたので確認をお願いします。updateできないのは悲しいですね。古く効率の悪い記述を求められるとしても、それが業務等の方針であれば仕方がないですね。それによってミスが生じるのであれば、古い環境を強制したことが原因と言い切るしか。

Comment: 追記いただきありがとうございます。確かに、テスト側のリスクが高まりすぎると、何のテストをしているんだ状態になってしまい本末転倒ですもんね……できる範囲で頑張ってみます。ありがとうございました。